# Gili islands to Mataram

Tags: public-transport, transportation, indonesia, sea-travel, lombok

I'm in Indonesia, I want to go from the [Gili islands](https://goo.gl/maps/fmUfb) to Mataram.

That is, from either of the islands called Gili Trawangan, Gili Meno, & Gili Air.

[image: Lombok map with Gili islands & Bangsal pointed out]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Comment: Note: I had to recreate this question as it was closed by some users, hence I could not answer it after I traveled to the Gili islands. see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51479/gili-islands-to-mataram-how-to

Answer (score 4):

This journey is broken down in 2 parts:

1. Go to Bangsal by sea
2. Bangsal to Mataram by land

---

#### Gili Air to Bangsal

1. **Public boats**: price is 12’000 IDR, departure is in the morning (around 7-8am), it takes 20 minutes. Just turn up early at the ticket office to buy your ticket & then wait for the boat to be fully booked so it can leave. I’m not sure how many public boats leave every morning.
2. **Shuttle boat**: price is 30’000 IDR, departure is at 08:30am, it takes 20 minutes.
3. **Speedboat**: price is 100’000 IDR, departure is 8 times a day (approximately every hour starting at 09:00am), it takes 20min.
4. **Charter boat**: price is 360’000 IDR, departure whenever you like, it takes 20 minutes. I guess this boat could welcome quite a few people so that’s a pretty good option if you are 4+ people or simply have the extra cash for it.

---

#### Gili Trawangan to Bangsal

I’d expect similar departure times/frequencies as it’s the most touristy of the three islands. Best thing to do to get more info is to go directly to the official ticket office in the small harbour of Gili Trawangan.

---

#### Gili Meno to Bangsal

I have not been to there myself but I was told it’s as touristy as Gili Air so I’d expect similar departure times/frequencies. Best thing to do to get more info is to try go directly to the official ticket office (if any) which is probably in the small harbour of Gili Meno.

---

#### Bangsal to Mataram

1. **Bemo**: walk from the harbour to the center of Bangsal (10min) to catch a bemo (minibus), it leaves whenever it's "full enough" with passengers (you may wait 15min), the price is 20'000 IDR per seat, it takes 25 minutes.
2. **Taxis**: walk from the harbour to the center of Bangsal (10min) to find taxis with "real" prices. Sorry I don't know the price, best is to ask a few of them to get a realistic idea of the price.

Note: there will be a gang of taxi drivers waiting for you (tourists) at the Bangsa harbour. They will try to convince you hire them at a incredibly high price (I was proposed to be driven to the Mataram airport for 100 USD!). Just say "no thanks" and walk away. They are not violent or aggressive, but mostly annoying.

See below a small map showing where to catch those Bemos & Taxi (note that I came across taxis on the way to that location).

[image: Map of Bangsal with harbour & bemo pick up location pointed out]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

---

All the prices for the Gili Air to Bangsal sea travel options are from the official ticket office from Gili Air, located in the small harbour, see picture of price list below.

[image: price list for boats from Gili Air]