# Labuan Bajo to Lombok by bus & ferry

Tags: transportation, indonesia, night-transport, komodo, lombok

I am in Indonesia, in Labuan Bajo (Flores) next to the Komodo national park, & I have been told it's possible to go to Lombok by bus & ferry.

[image: Map of Bali, Lombok, Sumbawa & Flores]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Comment: To those who marked this as duplicate: this is NOT a duplicate as I am asking the opposite direction as the question marked as duplicate of. The main concern is that because of this, boats & buses schedules are different, hence the answer (& journey) completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I have done research online and offline, as for this question: [Go from Lombok to Labuan Bajo by bus & ferry, how to?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51881/lombok-to-labuan-bajo-by-bus-ferry)

So I will answer it myself. But do add your answer/comments if you have anything to say!

The only things that are different with the linked question are:

- Departure time of **ferry** from **Labuan Bajo** is at **09:00**
- **Bemos** going from **Sape to Bima** are waiting in Sape for the ferry to arrive, so there is virtually no waiting time.
- **Bima to Mataram**, buses leaves at **19:00**. They know many passengers from Labuan Bajo are coming so they usually wait for you. Once in that bus, just put your coat on (cold AC) & have a nap.

---

Note that it is much nicer to do the journey this way rather than the other as the transports are all waiting for you to arrive from the long ferry ride. Rather than you waiting for the transports.